# Do Olympus lenses and filters for TG-3 or TG-4 fit TG-5?

Tags: olympus

Just curious whether some used TG-4 and TG-3 accesories are a good deal or a waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

> Do Olympus lenses and filters for TG-3 or TG-4 fit TG-5?

Yes - the design of the lens housing is the same. All of the cameras use the same [CLA-T01](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/859972-REG/Olympus_V323060BW000_CLA_T01_Conversion_Lens_Adapter.html/) converter to expand lens attachment possibilities.

> Just curious whether some used TG-4 and TG-3 accesories are a good deal or a waste of money.

This is completely dependent on the accessory. As a general rule, lens attachments are junk. But, there are some diamonds in the rough for accomplishing tasks outside the scope of the normal functioning of the camera.

Comment: Thank you, Hueco. I'm looking at filters and a telephoto lens. But not the graduated color lenses, which I'd rarely if ever use.

Comment: @CarolineJumper the filters will depend on the brand and individual quality (for example, cheap neutral density typically have color casts). The attachment lenses (telephoto, macro, etc) can be hit and miss. A lot of them use junk elements that will reduce resolution and increase aberrations. But, like I said, there are some *decent* ones out there. I’d highly advise review sites and good return policies.